# build deb file with compress tar.xz not tar.zst?

Tags: 21.10

I have upgrade my ubuntu from 21.04 to 21.10 and I have got the problem with install any packages after build it as deb file with this command

```
dpkg-deb -b DEB
```

I have got the compress file with tar.zst and that extension can not apply on dreambox

```
uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
```

How to build deb with tar.xz ?!
Or How to download dpkg ?!!

Comment: Which package are you talking about? What do you mean by installing the source file(s)?

Comment: my own build file .... How can build deb file with compress tar.xz ?!! That what I need only

Comment: Can you extract the source tarball and run `debuild` there? Assuming you have taken care of the debian directory structure correctly, it should work. Without more details, we really cannot help you further. We may be able to help if you share a source code repository (in GitHub/GitLab)

Comment: `I have got the compress file with tar.zst and that extension can not apply on dreambox` What do you mean by that? How did you get the .tar.zst file? Usually `.pkg.tar.zst` files are for Arch Linux.

Comment: As I said I use this command to build deb file `dpkg-deb -b DEB` so I have these files inside deb file `control.tar.zst` and `data.tar.zst` should be I have got like this  `control.tar.xz` and `data.tar.xz` .... So If I try to install the deb file I got this error `dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/test.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up`

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you run `debuild` in the source directory, instead if `dpkg-deb -b DEB` ?

Comment: /ipkg/ncam/DEB$ debuild `debuild: fatal error at line 679:
cannot find readable debian/changelog anywhere!
Are you in the source code tree?`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130876/discussion-between-fair-bird-and-archisman-panigrahi).

Comment: In that case, you need to create a proper debian/changelog and debian/control.

Comment: What is your directory structure? Post the output of the command `tree` in your source directory.

Comment: ```:~/home/DEB-test$ tree
.
├── DEBIAN
│   └── control
└── tmp
    └── installNcam.sh

2 directories, 2 files```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAICT, it should be `dpkg-deb -Zxz -b DEB`, where `-Z` specifies compression method `xz`.